# Prove that the homomorphism $\phi:R\to S^{-1}R$ is injective if and only if $S$ contains no zero-divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, division-algebras

Suppose that $S\subset R$ is a multiplicative set in $R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with identity $1\neq 0$. Prove that the homomorphism $\phi:R\to S^{-1}R$ is injective if and only if $S$ contains no zero-divisors.

I have an idea about how to approach this question, but I am not sure exactly how to structure it. For one direction, where we assume $\phi$ is injective, this means that $\ker(\phi)=\{0\}$, which I think means that there are no zero divisors in $R$, so there are no zero divisors in $S$ because it is a subset of $R$? Am I headed in the right direction?

Edit: I believe this question is different than the one it is marked as duplicate to, because that question uses the concept of monomorphisms which are not mentioned here.

Comment: Perhaps you could enquire what in general the kernel of $\phi$ is?

Comment: In general, $\ker(\phi)=\{r\in R|\phi(r)=0\}=\{r\in R|rs^{-1}=0\text{ for some }s\in S\}$, so if this is equal to zero, then we are saying that for each $r\in R$, there exists no $s\in S$ such that $rs^{-1}=0$.

Comment: Do you really mean $s^{-1}$ here? In general a multiplicatively closed set will not consist entirely of units.

Comment: I think I am assuming that $S$ consists only of invertible elements.

Comment: If $S$ consists only of invertible elements in $R$ then $\phi$ is an isomorphism, and there is really no point in considering $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct. In this case, I'm not really sure how to picture $\phi$.